# Apply Conditional Formatting Expression with VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make a conditional format for cell *rC*. If the sum of absolute values in a range is different from zero, it should trigger the condition.

The Conditional Formatting Expression works in worksheet.

The actual content of sB is more complicated, but I get the same error when trying the simple code below.

( **;** as I am on a Danish configuration):

```vb
sA = "ADDRESS(" & rC.Row & "+1;" & rC.Column & ";4)"
sB = "ADDRESS(" & rC.Row & "+2;" & rC.Column & ";4)"
rC.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
  Formula1:="=sum(abs(indirect(" & sA & ")" & ":" & "indirect(" & sB & ")))<>0"
```

It returns

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Stepping into the code the formula returns
**"=sum(abs(indirect(ADDRESS(4+1;8;4)):indirect(ADDRESS(4+2;8;4))))<>0"**, which works [returns *false*] when pasted into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it yields the same error. 
From Immediate (to confirm the change)  "=sum(abs(indirect(ADDRESS(4+1,8,4)):indirect(ADDRESS(4+2,8,4))))<>0"

Comment: Perhaps easier: `Formula1:="=SUM(ABS(OFFSET(" & rC.address(False; False) & ";1;0;2;1)))"`   CF formulas use the local list separator (unlike adding worksheet formulas in VBA where comma is standard unless using `FormulaLocal`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's possible to avoid both sA and sB completely, i.e.

```
 rC.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=SUM(ABS(" & rc.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1) & ":" & rc.Offset(2, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1) & "))<>0"
```